# California code for gas range ventilation

Tags: natural-gas

Is there a california code for gas range ventilation to the exterior of the house. Because I have a gas range that has a downdraft but the exhaust is hitting the wall of the the cabinet.

Comment: If California follows International Residential Code, see the second half of [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/75097/33).

Comment: Yes, California has adopted substantially all of the first 10 chapters of International Residential Code (2015), effective Jan 1, 2017. However, the "mechanical" code refers one to the "California Mechanical Code", i.e., IMC (2015). For reference: In the 2009 IMC, 501.2, domestic kitchen exhaust was clearly required to terminate outdoors, except for specifically designed recirculating systems. 505.1 was for domestic cooking downdraft. It has been seriously revamped and renumbered for 2015, and I'm not too familiar with the later version.